# Проверка на лишние символы в js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как сделать фильтрацию символов, вот у меня есть переменная, как мне проверить есть ли там символы из не русского/английского языка?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно проверить, есть ли в строке буквы некириллической письменности, можно при помощи такого регулярного выражения:

```js
const cyrillic = 'абв - эюя';
const mixed = 'абв - xyz';

const regexp = /(?!\p{Script_Extensions=Cyrillic})\p{L}/u;

console.log(regexp.test(cyrillic));
console.log(regexp.test(mixed));
```

Оно использует [Unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) вместе с [Negative lookahead assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions).

Это упрощённое регулярное выражение. Если вам нужен более точный и надёжный охват всех символов, которые могут использоваться в словах, вместо `\p{L}` воспользуйтесь примером из [Unicode-aware version of `\w`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes#unicode-aware-version-of-w).